# How to build a Silverlight Facebook client?

Tags: silverlight, facebook, twitter, client

As my final project I wanted to do **client for Facebook and Twitter** using the APIs available. But there is not much tutorial or guidance available for me to start this project. And the other idea was to build a **Game in Silverlight**, which have more tutorials and info on it.

I would prefer to do **social media client**, but if enough help is there.

Comment: You could try the Facebook .Net SDK here http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com. This SDK supports all of the newest Facebook Apis and authentication systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the Facebook Developer Toolkit?

http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/

If you want to access Facebook APIs from within Silverlight, it's where you should start.

This project leverages the Facebook Toolkit above:

http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/apps/facebookclient/sfcquickinstall.aspx

So far as I know, the source for it hasn't been released.  You could presumably do something similar, but open-source it.